# Number of unique values within a range in data-frame

Tags: r, plyr

From a data-frame, I want to extract the number of unique values (of X) within a certain range of Y (e.g. for every 0-100, 101-200, 201-300, etc. up to 3000).

Example df

```
X         Y
169     183
546      64
154     148
593     203
60      243
568     370
85      894
168     169
154     148
83      897
…
```

A time consuming way would be to run the following code for each range:

```
junk<-subset(df, Y > 0 & Y < 100)

length(unique(junk$record.no))
```

But I have to ask the experts - there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `by()` and `cut()`:

```
data <- data.frame(X=ceiling(rnorm(10000, 500, 10)), Y=runif(10000, 0, 3000))
data$Groups <- cut(data$Y, seq(0, 3000, 100)) # Create a categorical variable for each range

by(data$X, data$Group, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: +1 `table(data$Groups)` would work just fine at this point also. Be careful about overwriting the function `data`, with an object.

Answer (score 1):

This seems valid:

```
aggregate(DF$X, list(cut(DF$Y, seq(0, 1000, 100))), function(x) unique(x)) 
#    Group.1             x                                        #or length(unique(x))
#1   (0,100]           546
#2 (100,200] 169, 154, 168
#3 (200,300]       593, 60
#4 (300,400]           568
#5 (800,900]        85, 83
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a for loop based on the range you want and the size of the dataframe and then count the number of levels by converting to factor:

```
range <- 100 #based on example
loops <- nrow(df)/range
lvlMatrix <- matrix(nrow=0,ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("range","unique values")))
for(a in 1:loops){
  sub <- df[((a-1)*range):(range*a),]
  lvls<-nlevels(factor(sub$X))
  lvlMatrix <- rbind(lvlMatrix,cbind(paste(as.character((a-1)*range),"-",as.character(range*a),sep=""),lvls))
}
```